# I do not understand the purpose of this line of code, terrainMap[x, y] = Random.Range(1, 101) < iniChance ? 1 : 0;

Tags: c#

```
public void initPos()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            terrainMap[x, y] = Random.Range(1, 101) < iniChance ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

What does below portion of code do? this code is getting used in Unity as part of a script to procedural map generation.

< iniChance ? 1 : 0;

Comment: It sets a Random value to each element in array `terrainMap`. Each element will either get 1 or 0 assigned.
The likelihood of being 1 or 0 depends on the value of `iniChance`. Roughly spoken, the smaller iniChance is the more often you get 1's. The greater it is the more 0s you get.

Answer (score 1):

```
terrainMap[x, y] = Random.Range(1, 101) < iniChance ? 1 : 0;
```

is a shorthand expression for

```
var rndValueBetween1And101 = Random.Range(1, 101);
if (rndValueBetween1And101 < iniChance)
{
   terrainMap[x, y] =  1;
}
else
{
   terrainMap[x, y] =  0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you talking about
[?: ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

It is the short form of the if else conditions

```
condition ? statement 1 : statement 2
```